# ReCaptcha Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I am implementing Google reCaptcha Enterprise.
So far I am sending the request and getting back the token. But when I send the token with curl to create the assessment I am getting this error:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(400)
    ["message"]=>
    string(37) "Request contains an invalid argument."
    ["status"]=>
    string(16) "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I am not sure why.
My curl request looks like this:

```
$token = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
//echo "Token: " . $token;

$data = [
    'event' => [
        'token' => $token,
        'siteKey' => RECAPTCHAKEY,
        'expectedAction' => 'LOGIN'
    ]
];

echo 'data<br>' . json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$responseData = json_decode($response);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($responseData);
echo '</pre>';
```

The response that I am getting from google look like this (a little bit shortened):

```
data
{"event":{"token":"03AD1IbLACZr43YilgAgGSblh6cauhQmv9hic-hm7yPCApL-cFwth7MDaWvVKaIIf3fOiKsku7KbnL7VXArw3sbMuSQ0gpdEPhxAYrvAOOdT2kEE2uE9HBf_jTnk896LeK8Ae3Zj1ZHHMm2N-75v0jv-AB6faye77gM-6-KaiwAsS7X6_skfV_xE-VuPMOXhHf0HARnRi7DJm5aYaafxjoAj54RH7t-xbqQc_IDFUvVAAm8uGmoKpXTrweOFrrsh3SfekYJRYWZzBWlT1z0fGTdbeOrHcVTKaRY9wSEIFYubrKmYweQDLngx5x5d5oFAk0stHGPQojPLxDoUh6hSeglyorHJwjZkd3aervNoi_bz1ymP2fI24lg7jXSaIdqTU2YrwVKrnl2X6McNcKVAMS7I6Bnflsf-6_2mLCU2LzK68qUNrFfad6L0pQZn-twSiSjfhvpdctbAVqlMkUsZgqFjEn7zsC8iycMcUUHCOFxxlWMMth5RZ4e55CLAX3Hdmm27pzbe7OYDCjqGkLZgDNYxieLIXWH0ww88B5G5A39vpkLr0SMX396jWMJns7GKh8mNg3dzpl18R2-9t_rZsxyGrxRwCBAoDzvSsU39n-gj4SwXYUDRksj7n9OBMIN5Md-eQaCcKAh7XpvIQDe3-LVVukqi1vigm6KL2ZxZiqg0L-_M7KxJC7Sex7T5gqA4WMvGhfq1tHtneWTuVZs8T0ogIddcFBb4jHyfYc6g91aPCU6EiHnW-bm63qTc8g_oDOe6iITjKQQZAar5xPlLcowJdG780Ti_d2aFqSUSF6cM4T1AYxuwkgvyn89J2QcP0dlETyXqqGj7M4hk7ID9GY04B-q9CFFONegIe3VFCqj7xEdXBMDUpMdLTFHfE5UtTYmaZdSuC2NWvxVnx-UUoWCMXEE4lGgpayM6jVFcSW4PEJK2m656St6i7kTtJQivc9m2f3nToot1LkS1qvNKENvuA-RF9fP8WI4-fHByFa0-BoYEPmiW7tJ-_qD-gwm6_jczpdV2fu8di1y6C3GcpolAE8GqhH7nBHwsCHPeXIiOp6XIFobBrmKB42JT4XQS2_Ba2wIMhICnrAqVkmwADSjym9C1P--CntQopjgIWT9vDIvtLd67zdeMl2LRZOJtcWvwebYzxwSwZmZuxnjgXe6NU1GKhqsGfyoa7SqJ1PVkknw2W9bRRlS-ko32TtWE3slaMxL4qbbg7JX78iPg8f5Jhb2jM8kPhziCoEyCTsMOjugjTyLFx8uCXPDdxwqZdUQKuh4OEzUqJK7I4q7adTZ38fegPp2XLrm69yTPYxhqehniYiAU_wmvIXr1z3TYbj2sFvPyfUgzsbL0fVOmKd0w11xWKiFYHZTdpkPN7NMowmWfPd1CFoS2Pfd3nbIC5BOnUX","siteKey":"123456789ABCDE","expectedAction":"LOGIN"}}
```

I have no "expected action" set up on the form page.
I just have a form with two text fields and a button.

```
<form id="login-form" method='post' action='src/recaptcha.php' name='login-form'>
...
<button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-primary"
                        data-sitekey="<?php echo RECAPTCHAKEY; ?>"
                        data-callback='onSubmit'
                        data-action='submit'><?php echo $lan->getValue('login'); ?></button>
```

Comment: Check this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67577330/google-cloud-recaptchaenterprise-error-on-createassessment-request-contains) ,which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. With the rest API it was not possible to solve it. Finally I chose the google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise. With that it was possible to get an assessment.

Comment: Posted Answer for better community visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer for better community visibility.

OPs issue resolved with the help of `google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise`.

Creating an assessment by sending a request to the reCAPTCHA Enterprise API. You can use either the gcloud CLI or API key for authentication. Please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment) for more information.